# i tried Converting the predictor variable in a binary numeric variable and i keep getting the error, i have also tried checking online but no solution

Tags: python

please why do I keep getting this error:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

This is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('HR_Employee_Attrition.csv', header=0)
data.head()
#Convertin the predictor variable in a binary numeric variable
data_2= data['Attrition'].replace(to_replace='Yes', value=1, inplace=True)
data_2= data['Attrition'].replace(to_replace='No',  value=0, inplace=True)
#Let's convert all the categorical variables into dummy variables
data_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data_2)
data_dummies.head()
```

Comment: What's the trace? There's no call to `len` here, so you're likely passing `None` somewhere accidentally.

Comment: thank you @Carcigenicate, I am trying to Plot the correlation of the variables against Attrition, but I need to first perform necessary preprocessing, which is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Yes as I said though, what is the trace of the error?

Comment: Thank you @Carcigenicate I sorted it out. I used the .loc function to replace yes and no with 1 and 0. I am new to IT but making gradual progress.